# Will `sudo reboot` on KVM host gracefully poweroff guest VMs?

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Currently I manually poweroff each KVM guest before rebooting the host.  However, this is getting old and now I am up to about 20 guest machines.

Can I trust Ubuntu Server 12.04 to do the Right Thing and hold off on completing a shutdown until the last KVM client is off?

Alternatively is there an easier way to shut all the guests off gracefully?

Comment: Something to think about: a shutdown script that would send some sort of "shutdown all VMs" signal to KVM. The idea needs some fleshing out, but if KVM supports command-line control, it wouldn't be too hard to create a simple shutdown script to do that.

Comment: Yes - this could be done via the `virsh` command, I'm looking for something more out-of-the-box.  According to this launchpad bug, it may already Just Work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kvm/+bug/350936

Comment: On RedHat they have a script called `libvirt-guests` which takes care of this automatically, but for whatever reason, Ubuntu doesn't include this script in their package. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/0.9.8-2ubuntu1

Comment: ok - looking `/etc/init/libvirt-bin` it appears that the necessary code is in there to do this.  I just completed a test run and it did work, but I needed to increase the timeout that was in that file from 30 seconds to 2 minutes.

Comment: As a system admin I'm shocked to see the timeout in `/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf` is ONLY 30 seconds.  Checking the code I see this isn't even per VM, it is total.  I've seen a physical (non-VM) production server that take 15min to shutdown on new fast hardware after a fresh install and databases restored. My Work's current main VM server takes nearly 10mins to shutdown due to the 30VMs with multiple databases etc.

Comment: I just learned you are supposed to put changes into a new `/etc/init/libvirt-bin.override`  file instead of changing the `.conf` file.  According to http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files and https://sebastian.marsching.com/wiki/Linux/KVM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is done automatically, according to this fixed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/350936

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/200751/can-kvm-suspend-or-shutdown-guests-automatically-on-host-shutdown

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 does not actually do this.